# Apt Unmet dependecies: libefl-bin

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dependencies

I am encountering an error when I run `apt-get upgrade`. It appears I have a package installed that has unmet dependencies.

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux kbu 3.19.0-56-generic #62~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 11:03:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is the output from `apt-get upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libefl-bin : Depends: libefl (= 201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1) but 201603242131-31876~ubuntu14.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Here is the output from running `apt-get -f install`:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libefl
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libefl
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 3,032 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,278 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/enlightenment-git/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main libefl amd64 201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1 [3,032 kB]
Fetched 2,873 kB in 14s (193 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 217178 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libefl_201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libefl (201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1) over (201603242131-31876~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libefl_201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libelementary.so.1.17.99', which is also in package libelementary 201603242216-12490~ubuntu14.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libefl_201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

...and the output from `apt-cache showpkg libefl`:

```
Package: libefl
Versions: 
201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_enlightenment-git_ppa_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_enlightenment-git_ppa_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: c3762b13d2835617f77263b388ba31ad
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_enlightenment-git_ppa_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: c3762b13d2835617f77263b388ba31ad

201603242131-31876~ubuntu14.04.1 (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/dpkg/status
                  MD5: cc1a6fd5b0ea2294658de3cd7b486a53


Reverse Depends: 
  libefl:i386,libefl
  e20,libefl
  libefl-dbg,libefl 201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1
  libefl-dev,libefl 201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1
  libefl-bin,libefl 201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1
  terminology,libefl
  evas-loaders,libefl
  emodule-comp-scale,libefl
  ecomorph,libefl
  emodule-exebuf,libefl
  emodule-everything-websearch,libefl
  emodule-everything-wallpaper,libefl
  emodule-everything-tracker,libefl
  emodule-everything-places,libefl
  emodule-everything-pidgin,libefl
  emodule-everything-mpris,libefl
  emodule-everything-aspell,libefl
  emodule-engage,libefl
  emodule-empris,libefl
  emodule-elfe,libefl
  libelementary,libefl
  libedbus1,libefl
  emodule-wlan,libefl
  emodule-winselector,libefl
  emodule-winlist-ng,libefl
  emodule-weather,libefl
  emodule-uptime,libefl
  emodule-taskbar,libefl
  emodule-snow,libefl
  emodule-slideshow,libefl
  emodule-rain,libefl
  emodule-moon,libefl
  emodule-mem,libefl
  emodule-mail,libefl
  emodule-itask,libefl
  emodule-flame,libefl
  emodule-execwatch,libefl
  emodule-diskio,libefl
  emodule-deskshow,libefl
  emodule-cpu,libefl
  emodule-alarm,libefl
  ecomorph-core,libefl
  libelementary-bin,libefl
  e17,libefl
Dependencies: 
201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1 - libbulletcollision2.81 (0 (null)) libbulletdynamics2.81 (0 (null)) libbulletsoftbody2.81 (0 (null)) libc6 (2 2.17) libdbus-1-3 (2 1.5.12) libfontconfig1 (2 2.9.0) libfreetype6 (2 2.2.1) libfribidi0 (2 0.19.2) libgcc1 (2 1:4.1.1) libgif4 (2 4.1.4) libgl1-mesa-glx (16 (null)) libgl1 (0 (null)) libglib2.0-0 (2 2.37.3) libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (2 1.0.0) libgstreamer1.0-0 (2 1.0.0) libharfbuzz0b (2 0.9.4) libjpeg8 (2 8c) liblinearmath2.81 (0 (null)) libluajit-5.1-2 (0 (null)) libmount1 (2 2.20.1) libpng12-0 (2 1.2.13-4) libpulse0 (2 1:0.99.1) libsndfile1 (2 1.0.20) libssl1.0.0 (2 1.0.0) libstdc++6 (2 4.1.1) libtiff5 (2 4.0.3) libudev1 (2 199) libwebp5 (0 (null)) libx11-6 (2 2:1.2.99.901) libxcomposite1 (2 1:0.3-1) libxcursor1 (4 1.1.2) libxdamage1 (2 1:1.1) libxext6 (0 (null)) libxfixes3 (0 (null)) libxi6 (2 2:1.2.99.4) libxinerama1 (0 (null)) libxrandr2 (2 2:1.2.99.3) libxrender1 (0 (null)) libxss1 (0 (null)) libxtst6 (0 (null)) zlib1g (2 1:1.1.4) libecore-con1 (0 (null)) libecore-con1:i386 (0 (null)) libecore-evas1 (0 (null)) libecore-evas1:i386 (0 (null)) libecore-fb1 (0 (null)) libecore-fb1:i386 (0 (null)) libecore-file1 (0 (null)) libecore-file1:i386 (0 (null)) libecore-imf1 (0 (null)) libecore-imf1:i386 (0 (null)) libecore-ipc1 (0 (null)) libecore-ipc1:i386 (0 (null)) libecore-x1 (0 (null)) libecore-x1:i386 (0 (null)) libecore0 (0 (null)) libecore0:i386 (0 (null)) libecore1 (0 (null)) libecore1:i386 (0 (null)) libedbus2 (0 (null)) libedbus2:i386 (0 (null)) libedje1 (0 (null)) libedje1:i386 (0 (null)) libeet0 (0 (null)) libeet0:i386 (0 (null)) libeet1 (0 (null)) libeet1:i386 (0 (null)) libeeze1 (0 (null)) libeeze1:i386 (0 (null)) libefreet1 (0 (null)) libefreet1:i386 (0 (null)) libeina0 (0 (null)) libeina0:i386 (0 (null)) libeina1 (0 (null)) libeina1:i386 (0 (null)) libeio0 (0 (null)) libeio0:i386 (0 (null)) libembryo0 (0 (null)) libembryo0:i386 (0 (null)) libemotion1 (0 (null)) libemotion1:i386 (0 (null)) libevas0 (0 (null)) libevas0:i386 (0 (null)) libevas1 (0 (null)) libevas1:i386 (0 (null)) libefl:i386 (0 (null)) 
201603242131-31876~ubuntu14.04.1 - libbulletcollision2.81 (0 (null)) libbulletdynamics2.81 (0 (null)) libbulletsoftbody2.81 (0 (null)) libc6 (2 2.17) libdbus-1-3 (2 1.5.12) libfontconfig1 (2 2.9.0) libfreetype6 (2 2.2.1) libfribidi0 (2 0.19.2) libgcc1 (2 1:4.1.1) libgif4 (2 4.1.4) libgl1-mesa-glx (16 (null)) libgl1 (0 (null)) libglib2.0-0 (2 2.37.3) libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (2 1.0.0) libgstreamer1.0-0 (2 1.0.0) libharfbuzz0b (2 0.9.4) libjpeg8 (2 8c) liblinearmath2.81 (0 (null)) libluajit-5.1-2 (0 (null)) libmount1 (2 2.20.1) libpng12-0 (2 1.2.13-4) libpulse0 (2 1:0.99.1) libsndfile1 (2 1.0.20) libssl1.0.0 (2 1.0.0) libstdc++6 (2 4.1.1) libtiff5 (2 4.0.3) libudev1 (2 199) libwebp5 (0 (null)) libx11-6 (2 2:1.2.99.901) libxcomposite1 (2 1:0.3-1) libxcursor1 (4 1.1.2) libxdamage1 (2 1:1.1) libxext6 (0 (null)) libxfixes3 (0 (null)) libxi6 (2 2:1.2.99.4) libxinerama1 (0 (null)) libxrandr2 (2 2:1.2.99.3) libxrender1 (0 (null)) libxss1 (0 (null)) libxtst6 (0 (null)) zlib1g (2 1:1.1.4) libecore-con1 (0 (null)) libecore-con1:i386 (0 (null)) libecore-evas1 (0 (null)) libecore-evas1:i386 (0 (null)) libecore-fb1 (0 (null)) libecore-fb1:i386 (0 (null)) libecore-file1 (0 (null)) libecore-file1:i386 (0 (null)) libecore-imf1 (0 (null)) libecore-imf1:i386 (0 (null)) libecore-ipc1 (0 (null)) libecore-ipc1:i386 (0 (null)) libecore-x1 (0 (null)) libecore-x1:i386 (0 (null)) libecore0 (0 (null)) libecore0:i386 (0 (null)) libecore1 (0 (null)) libecore1:i386 (0 (null)) libedbus2 (0 (null)) libedbus2:i386 (0 (null)) libedje1 (0 (null)) libedje1:i386 (0 (null)) libeet0 (0 (null)) libeet0:i386 (0 (null)) libeet1 (0 (null)) libeet1:i386 (0 (null)) libeeze1 (0 (null)) libeeze1:i386 (0 (null)) libefreet1 (0 (null)) libefreet1:i386 (0 (null)) libeina0 (0 (null)) libeina0:i386 (0 (null)) libeina1 (0 (null)) libeina1:i386 (0 (null)) libeio0 (0 (null)) libeio0:i386 (0 (null)) libembryo0 (0 (null)) libembryo0:i386 (0 (null)) libemotion1 (0 (null)) libemotion1:i386 (0 (null)) libevas0 (0 (null)) libevas0:i386 (0 (null)) libevas1 (0 (null)) libevas1:i386 (0 (null)) libefl:i386 (0 (null)) 
Provides: 
201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1 - 
201603242131-31876~ubuntu14.04.1 - 
Reverse Provides:
```

My knowledge of the `apt` package manager is pretty limited, and my searches for more info have not turned up anything useful for dealing with this issue.

I have also tried some of the common solutions for fixing unmet dependecies (such as `apt-get clean` and attempting to upgrade again). Any more insight into what the output of some of these commands mean is very much appreciated if a specific solution is not obvious.

**Edit**

Output of `apt-cache policy libefl-bin libefl`:

```
libefl-bin:
  Installed: 201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/enlightenment-git/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libefl:
  Installed: 201603242131-31876~ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
     201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/enlightenment-git/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 201603242131-31876~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The output of `sudo apt-get purge libefl`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libefl-bin : Depends: libefl (= 201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libelementary : Depends: libefl but it is not going to be installed
 terminology : Depends: libefl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Paste the output of `apt-cache policy libefl-bin libefl` into your question, please.

Comment: Alright, added the output.

Comment: You have a file level conflict between `libefl` (at least the `201604022131-32022` version) and `libelementary`. `apt-cache policy libelementary terminology`, please.

Comment: Note: put a @ + user name to notify someone of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this thread within minutes of you posting it. It seems this problem has only come up in the last few days, and is related to the Terminology package.

I more or less followed these instructions to get apt working again: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2319182

I couldn't follow them exactly due to purging libefl, so I first used dpkg to remove terminology, then libelementary, and reinstalled libefl. After that, apt was happy again.

Comment: That did it. I uninstalled terminology using `dpkg -r terminology`, then removed `libefl` the same way. The I reinstalled `libefl` and all was well. I'd +1 but I don't have enough rep just yet. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I didn't have to remove libefl. What I did was
  dpkg -r terminology &&
  dpkg -r libelementary &&
  apt-get -f install

Answer (score 0):

For me forcing the installation via `dpkg` worked:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libefl_201604022131-32022~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb
```

after that:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Forcing stuff is not a good idea unless you really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was a little different. I had to do:

```
sudo dpkg -r libelementary
sudo apt-get purge terminology
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

*RESTART MACHINE*

```
sudo apt-get install terminology
```

Then:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libefl-bin_201604032132-32025~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libefl:
 evas-loaders depends on libefl.

dpkg: error processing package libefl (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libefl
```

Disabling the PPA of englightenment fixed it for me.